# What is Feature in Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 EE cost near by $22K / Year

What is features available as support?

Gives server in this cost and any support for custom development ?

Comment: i don't know why mark as duplicate i have mention its provide server or not and customization support and i have already read all docs but not found this answer.

Comment: The license cost you reference does not include hosting or custom development. Only the EE software and official support of it.

Comment: I have purchased ECE but i dont know how to setup in my local?

Comment: Its directly provide Staging site with no file edit

Answer (score 0):

According to [Magento EE Customer Support Guide](https://magento.com/sites/default/files/cu_pdf/content_small_one_column/Magento_EE_Customer_Support_Guide_April_2016.pdf), Technical Support responsibilities include, but are not limited to:

> - Handling inbound phone calls and accurately documenting your support requests into our case management system
> - Performing initial problem investigation and when possible, problem replication and isolation
> - Setting appropriate expectations regarding response times, follow-up, and needed information based on your support agreement and
>     the priority of the issue being reported
> - Collaborating with our sustaining engineering group and product engineering whenever patches or hot fixes may be required
> - Collaborating with product development and product engineering to address feature requests and other product enhancements